# How can I use showDialog with await

Tags: async-await, flutter

I have three examples of showDialog. I presume that _showAlert1 is correct, however it uses  2 functions to achieve it.  _showAlert2 also works, however I presume it is not correct because I believe that showDialog is async, and I presume that this function relies on the dialog being displayed in sufficient time. _showAlert3 does not work because the dialog stays on the screen and does not clear.

If _showAlert2 although it works is incorrect for the above reason, could someone please show me how this should be structured so that this can be done in one function.

**Examples:**

```
void _showAlert0(BuildContext context, String text, int seconds) async {
    return await showDialog(
        barrierDismissible: false,
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
              title: Text("Error"),
              content: Text(text),
            ));
  }

  void _showAlert1(BuildContext context, String text, int seconds) async {
    _showAlert0(context, text, seconds);
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: seconds));
    Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
  }

  void _showAlert2(BuildContext context, String text, int seconds) async {
    showDialog(
        barrierDismissible: false,
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
              title: Text("Error"),
              content: Text(text),
            ));
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: seconds));
    Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
  }

void _showAlert3(BuildContext context, String text, int seconds) async {
    await showDialog(
        barrierDismissible: false,
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
              title: Text("Error"),
              content: Text(text),
            ));
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: seconds));
    Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
}
```

Comment: "how this should be structured so that this can be done in one function?"

Comment: But what are you trying to do here? It seems you want to pop the dialog automatically? If that's the case, why not just do it from inside the dialog builder? Just add a `future.delayed` inside the AlertDialog builder and pop from there. Just don't `await` it.

Comment: I think I've made it perfectly clear what I'm trying to achieve. "how this should be structured so that this can be done in one function?" It's not hard to post an answer. Why not post an answer if you know how it can be done and I'll try it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if there is a better way, but the following appears to work. Note the "then" clause on the call to showDialog().

```
void _showAlert3(BuildContext context, String text, int seconds) async {
    showDialog(
        barrierDismissible: false,
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
              title: Text("Error"),
              content: Text(text),
            )).then((val) {});
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: seconds));
    Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
  }
```

**As for trolls, RTFQ ("structured so that this can be done in one function") and if you don't want to help then go away.**